# OneNote 2016 Add-In Options

Tags: javascript, c#, onenote, onenote-api

I've been looking into options to extend some functionality within OneNote via code. I've found references to Comm Add-Ins and Node.Js Add-Ins. I went with the Node.Js route, but I can't figure out how to add the Add-In in to OneNote. It seems like the Node.Js Add-in is only built for OneNote Online which I don't have. Is this true?

What options do I have to create an Add-In for OneNote 2016? Do my options expand if I use OneNote for Windows 10?

Thank you!